# GWT Composite best practices

Tags: gwt, composite

I'm learning GWT and have started to get the hang of it.  I'm at the point where my code is getting to be a spaghetti mess so I'm going back and factoring reasonable bits of it out as Composites.  The first problem I ran into was that my tool support failed to give the new Composite class an initWidget() method.  It did include a default constructor.
For the time being, I've simply filled in my overridden `initWidget()` method with a call to `super(initWidget(w))`  My project compiles and runs as expected, though I feel as though I must be missing something.

What should I keep in mind when overriding init and what if anything do i need to place in the constructor.  Is there anything else that I need to know or does it just boil down to regular old Java after this?

Clarification - It has occurred to me that there are probably different answers to this question depending on whether you intend to release said `Composite` classes as part of a library or simply part of your stand-alone app.  I in particular have no intention at this time of developing externally useful components (mainly because I'm so green in this particular technology.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to do. But for all the Composite's I've written I've never overridden the initWidget method. Because Composite itself doesn't need to be initialized with a constructor, i.e. no need to call super() my constructors of widgets extending composite look something like:

```
public mywidget() {
  SomePanel p = new SomePanel();
  ....
  initWidget(p);
}
```

As a best practice, imo, only the widget extending Composite should call it's 'own' initWidget.

Comment: I think this is probably the answer to my whole set of problems surrounding custom widgets.  I was also getting into a situation where the gui tools wouldnt render many of my custom widgets, most likely cuz neither my constructor nor init calls were correct.  I'll check it out when i get home... thx

Answer (score 2):

"[GWT Conference: Best Practices for Building Libraries](http://web.archive.org/web/20091027034401/http://www.pathf.com/blogs/2007/12/gwt-conferenc-9/)" gives a couple of tips. You should also look at the source of GWT and at the source of one of the libraries for GWT (like [gwt-ext](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-ext/))

[EDIT] I just saw another option: [suco](http://code.google.com/p/suco/). From the description:

> A micro library that helps to maintain your GWT client code clean and modular.